# How to restrict parent on the attribute?

Tags: xsd

Take a look at [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_complex_anyattribute.asp).

Now in the attribute.xsd there is an gender attribute defined. But as I understand I can use this attribute wherever the family.xsd would have anyAttribute.

Is it possible to restrict gender attribute to a certain parent based on parent's name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using `<xs:redefine>` which lets you redefine types and groups.

Answer (score 0):

Generally attributes are allowed only if a complex type is especially defined to allow the wanted attributes. On the other side generally `<xs:anyAttribute>` is used only when you want to allow any attributes (possibly with namespace restrictions) in this complex type.

#### I see this question could be interpreted in two different ways

1. Is there a way to use `<xs:anyAttribute>` but actually allow only certain kind of attributes
2. Is there a way to use `<xs:anyAttribute>` but disallow one certain attribute

Actually I don't have any good answers, I only have untested hacks.

#### Case number 1

This can be achieved using `namespace` attribute on `<xs:anyAttribute>`. Default value for `namespace` is `##any` which allows attributes from any namespace or without a namespace. Instead of ##any you can use either

1. `##other`, which allows any namespaced attribute but not an attribute belonging to the target namespace of the schema
   *or*
2. a whitespace separated list of URIs of allowed namespaces. This list can also contain wildcards `##targetNamespace` (which allows attributes from the target namespace of the schema) and `##local` (which allows attributes without a namespace)

Disallowing only attributes without a namespace doesn't seem to be possible.

If a schema has a target namespace, then all the globally defined attributes belong to that target namespace. So the w3schools' example seems in fact to be incorrect because they defined the attribute `gender` globally in a schema with a target namespace, yet they used it without a namespace prefix (default namespace doesn't apply to attributes).

#### Case number 2

This **might** be achieved with `<xs:attribute name="gender" use="prohibited"/>`. Attributes with `use="prohibited"` cannot be included. However I have never investigated is it allowed to use such attribute definition when the `<xs:anyAttribute>` element is present. Attribute `use` is not allowed on global attribute definitions so globally prohibiting the use of an attribute is not possible in this way.

Answer (score -1):

My knowledge of XML technologies is rather brief so take this with a pinch of salt.

You can use gender (male|female) in place of other attributes, as it would be syntactically correct XML.

However if you are checking if your XML is valid and well formed, then you need to write a DTD or preferably a schema document, to check where the gender attribute is allowed to be used

Comment: face palm, Sorry, I glanced over the W3C link to quickly to realise it wasn't the XMl tutorial.